# Adding tokens to autoreply message of contact form in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms, emails

I would like to switch on the core's contact form category function and ad some extra category to my contact form but I was wondering that in auto reply I can't use tokens or acess the field values like sender's name wich would be very great!
For solving this issue I don't like to use webform module becouse I would like to keep things as simple as I can.
Is it possible to send html mail from here somehow? 
I think a module must be exists for solving this but I can not find.
I would be appreciate any good idea.

Thanks 
Adam

Comment: Webform is as simple as it gets for setting up forms. It also makes sending emails with submitted form values very easy! I would recommend Webform every time for a use case like this

Comment: Thanks but I do not like to use webform for it becouse sending auto reply is a part of the core so I would like to use this if it is possible. I can send html mail by mime mail and mail system only what I need is adding some field value the name of sender in my auto reply message.

Comment: I can solve it here is the solution:
You have to add this to _contact_mail_alter(&$message) {} function:
// Adding Dear sender name, to auto reply message template:
  if ($message['id'] == 'contact_page_autoreply') {
    $dear_sender_text = t('Dear %sender, ', array('%sender' => $message['params']['name'])); 
    array_unshift($message['body'], $dear_sender_text);
  }